# why need seeAllData = true in test class when use connectAPI

Tags: unit-test, connect-api, seealldata

In my controller i'm using connectApi and my class functionality is working fine but the issue is when i'm using in my Test class (SeeAllData=true) it's covered 100% but seeAllData = true is not considering in best practice what the alternate to avoid seeAllData true.

without seeAllData true its throw an error  **System.UnsupportedOperationException: ConnectApi methods are not supported in data siloed tests. Please use @IsTest(SeeAllData=true).**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The alternative to using `seeAllData=true` is applying a mocking or delegate pattern so that the Connect API is not called in test context, but you can still validate behavior. Here's a simple and very explicit example (no `StubProvider`):

```
public class PostsToChatter {
    public interface ChatterPoster {
        void postToChatter(Id parentRecord, String text);
    }

    @TestVisible private class RealChatterPoster implements ChatterPoster {
        public void postToChatter(Id parentRecord, String text) {
            if (!Test.isRunningTest()) callConnectAPIHere(parentRecord, text);
            // Note that if we keep this minimal (one line) we still obtain full code coverage even though the Connect API call does not actually go through.
        }
    }

    @TestVisible private ChatterPoster myPoster;


    // ... constructors and code ...

    public PostsToChatter() {
        // Add a default delegate (the real Chatter poster class
        myPoster = new RealChatterPoster();
    }

    public void doSomethingRequiringAChatterPost() {
        // ... stuff happens ...
        myPoster.postToChatter(someId, someText);
    }
}
```

Then, in test context, we have the freedom to inject a completely different class that implements `PostsToChatter.ChatterPoster`, but doesn't really call the Connect API. Meanwhile, we've kept our actual-Chatter delegate so tiny and simple that **we can still call it in test context** to get the code coverage, even though we can't validate its behavior like we ought to.

```
@isTest
public static class PostsToChatter_TEST {
    private class MockChatterPoster implements PostsToChatter.ChatterPoster {
        public Id expectedId;
        public String expectedString;
        public Integer timesCalled = 0;

        public void postToChatter(Id parentRecord, String text) {
            System.assertEquals(expectedId, parentRecord, 'correct parent');
            System.assertEquals(expectedString, text, 'correct post body');
            timesCalled++;
        }
    }

    @isTest
    public static void testTheClass() {
        PostsToChatter p = new PostsToChatter();
        p.myPoster = new MockChatterPoster();

        // ... invoke class functionality...

        System.assertEquals(1, p.myPoster.timesCalled, 'chatter post called');
        // Post contents validated in the mock - or do it here if preferred.
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Since we cannot create chatter API related records in test class, we have to use organization data instead. To use organization data, we should place `@seealldata=true` at the beginning of test class to resolve the issues.

From [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/connectAPI_TestingApex.htm):

> Most Chatter in Apex methods require access to real organization data, and fail unless used in test methods marked @IsTest(SeeAllData=true).